# How to set up dark/light mode in Django?

Tags: django

I'm working on Django project and I purchase the HTML theme. Within the theme there is option for light and dark theme, by default you have light theme, but if I wand dark theme I need to add class to body: `<body class="theme--dark">`.

I'm trying to think a way to add switch at menu and with if statement to change the theme, but this is bit tricky since I don't have view for base.html

I'm not sure how to do this and I'm not sure what to google to find appropriate solution. Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: You ought to save the user’s preference in session or local storage if you want it to apply to just that device. If it will apply to every device of the user, then creating a record in the database will suffice.

Comment: I decided that I'm going to go with user preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is just **light** and **dark** themes, a boolean statement will do.

You should have a record table for user preferences seeing that preferred theme is just one feature you might want to remember for your user.

With that in mind, this will give you what you need:

```html
<body {% if not user_preference.theme_is_light %} class="theme--dark" {% endif %}>
```

The assumption is that there is a `user_preference` table for user preferences and it has a column for `theme_is_light`.